# Line jump before float

Tags: c

I have a problem with function

```
void imprimir_producto(t_producto);
```

A line break is being printed before float. I think what the problem is in function `t_producto leer_producto(void);` also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Producto
{
    int codigo_producto;
    char descripcion[20];
    float precio_unitario;

} t_producto;

float aplicar_iva(float precio_base);
void emitir_saludo(void);
void imprimir_producto(t_producto);
t_producto leer_producto(void);

int main()
{

    t_producto productos[2];
    t_producto producto;
    char decision;
    int i, cantidad;
    float total;

    cantidad =0;
    total = 0.0;

    emitir_saludo();

    while(cantidad <2)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("\nHay %d productos en el carrito. ¿Quiere pasar otro producto? [s/n]: ",cantidad);
            decision = getchar();
            while(getchar()==EOF);
        }while(decision != 's' && decision != 'S' && decision != 'n' && decision != 'N');

        if(decision=='n' || decision == 'N')
        {
            break;
        }

        producto = leer_producto();
        productos[cantidad++] = producto;
    }
    puts("\nPRODUCTOS:\n");
    for(i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
    {
        imprimir_producto(productos[i]);
        total += productos[i].precio_unitario;
        //es lo mismo que total = productos[i].precio_unitario + toal;
    }

    printf("\nTotal deproductos: %d\n\n",cantidad);
    printf("Precio total sin IVA: %.2f\n",total);
    printf("Precio total con IVA: %.2f\n",aplicar_iva(total));
    printf("\nBuenos dias.\n");


    return 0;   
}

float aplicar_iva(float precio_base)
{
    return precio_base * 1.21;
}

void emitir_saludo(void)
{
    printf("\n* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *");
    printf("\n* *    PROGRAMA SUPERMERCADO    * *\n");
    printf("* *  La calidad es lo primero   * *\n");
    printf("* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *\n");
}

void imprimir_producto(t_producto t)
{
    printf("%d %s %f\n",t.codigo_producto,t.descripcion,t.precio_unitario);
}

t_producto leer_producto(void)
{
    t_producto p;
    char entrada[80];

    printf("\nCodigo producto: ");
    fgets(entrada,10,stdin);
    if(entrada[strlen(entrada)+1] == 'n')
    {
        entrada[strlen(entrada)+1] == '\0';
    }
    p.codigo_producto = (int) strtol(entrada,NULL,10);

    printf("Descripcion: ");
    fgets(p.descripcion,20,stdin);
    if(p.descripcion[strlen(p.descripcion)+1] == 'n')
    {
        p.descripcion[strlen(p.descripcion)+1] == '\0';
    }


    printf("Precio: " );
    fgets(entrada,10,stdin);
    if(entrada[strlen(entrada)+1] == 'n')
    {
        entrada[strlen(entrada)+1] = '\0';
    }
    p.precio_unitario = strtof(entrada,NULL);

    return p;
}
```

Comment: `if(entrada[strlen(entrada)+1] == 'n')` - what are you checking at `strlen(entrada)+1` index and why? That's beyond the end of the string. And what is the importance of `'n'`?

Comment: I was wrong to write, but I corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You have twice written `== 'n'` instead of `== '\n'`. (I presume that you were trying to get rid of a trailing newline.)
2. In the same two places you have erroneously looked for the character at `[strlen()+1]` instead of `[strlen()-1]`. Consider also what happens when `strlen()` is zero.

Comment: Lol, Thanks I didn't realize that I put 'n'
but, i have a question... I understand that strlen returns the size of the array without counting the '\ 0', for example, if the array is size 10 plus the \ 0 is 11, so I put strlen + 1

Comment: @EmiliOrtega: Let's say that the string is `"abc"`. `strlen("abc")` is 3. `"abc"[0]` is `'a'`, `"abc"[1]` is `'b'` and `"abc"[2]` is `'c'`. In general, the first character in the string has index `[0]` and the last has index `[strlen()-1]`. The final `'\0'` is at `[strlen()]`.

Comment: A safe idiom for zapping the newline at the end of a string is `entrada[strcspn(entrada, "\n")] = '\0';` — if there is no newline, it writes a null byte over the null byte.